# Submitting form data to database

Tags: forms, submit, form-submit, atk4

I have a model 'Post' and a form, where this model 'includes', but I can't submit data from form to db table, here is source:
**page:**

```
$form = $this->add('Form');
$form->setModel('Post', array('title', 'category', 'date', 'body'));    
$form->addSubmit('Добавить');
if($form->isSubmitted()){
$form->js()->execute();
}
```

**model:**

```
$this->addField('slug')->caption('Ссылка');
$this->addField('author')->setValueList($user)->caption('Автор');
$this->addField('category')->setValueList($category)->caption('Категория');
$this->addField('previewIMG')->type('image')->caption('Изображение');
$this->addField('title')->caption('Заголовок');
$this->addField('date')->type('date')->defaultValue(date('Ymd'))->caption('Дата');
$this->addField('body')->type('text')->caption('Текст поста');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$form = $this->add('Form');
$form->setModel('Post', array('title', 'category', 'date', 'body'));    
$form->addSubmit('Добавить');
if($form->isSubmitted()){
    $form->update();           <------------------
    $form->js()->univ()->successMessage('Добавлено')->execute();
}
```